# Simple "lineno" macro that doesn't work

Tags: lineno

I'm trying to automate the command `\linelabel` in a way that it could create its own label name. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
\newcounter{countone}
\newcounter{counttwo}
\newcommand{\markline}{\stepcounter{countone}\linelabel{liner\thecountone}}
\newcommand{\refline}{\stepcounter{counttwo}\ref{liner\thecounttwo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers}
``Hello, here is some\markline text without a meaning.\\ 
This text\markline should show, how a printed text will\\ 
look like at this place. If you read\markline this text, you will get\\ 
no information. Really\markline? Is there no information?\\ 
Is there a difference\markline between this text and some\\ 
nonsense like ``Huardest gefburn''? Kjift – Never mind\markline!'' 
\end{linenumbers}

Here, I have the marked lines: \refline, \refline, \refline, \refline and \refline.
\end{document}
```

This gives me:
[image]

In my thinking, those scattered `\markline` over the text would be `\linelabel{liner1}`, `\linelabel{liner2}`, `\linelabel{liner3}`, etc. And then, when I call `\refline` it would call the label accordingly. What am I doing wrong? Sometimes, depending on where I put the command `\markline`, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the code in `lineno.sty` which does no expansion of the argument to `\linelabel`; since the arguments are eventually expanded during the next call of the output routine, the counter value used is the last in the page, in your case, 6.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
\newcounter{countone}
\newcounter{counttwo}
\newcommand{\markline}{\stepcounter{countone}\linelabel{liner\thecountone}}
\newcommand{\refline}{\stepcounter{counttwo}\ref{liner\thecounttwo}}

\makeatletter
\def\@LN@postlabel#1{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    % make sure to expand the argument to \linelabel before adding it
    % to \@LN@labellist
    \noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\@LN@labellist{#1\noexpand\@lt}%
  }\x
  \vadjust{\penalty-\@Mllbcodepen}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers}
``Hello, here is some\markline text without a meaning.\\ 
This text\markline should show, how a printed text will\\ 
look like at this place. If you read\markline this text, you will get\\ 
no information. Really\markline? Is there no information?\\ 
Is there a difference\markline between this text and some\\ 
nonsense like ``Huardest gefburn''? Kjift – Never mind\markline!'' 
\end{linenumbers}

Here, I have the marked lines: \refline, \refline, \refline, \refline\ and \refline.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `\linelabel` works exactly, but the problem seems to be that expansion happens too late. When you call `\linelabel{liner\thecountone}`, the `liner\thecountone` part seems to not be expanded immediately. Instead it seems to happen somewhen at the end of the `linenumbers` environment. At that point `\thecountone` is `6`, so all labels get the same number.

You can make expansion happen immediately, though, using TeX's `\edef` primitive in the definition of `\markline`:

```
\newcommand{\markline}{%
    \stepcounter{countone}%
    \edef\temp{liner\thecountone}%
    \expandafter\linelabel\expandafter{\temp}%
}
```

With the labels defined correctly now, you get the desired result:

[image]

Also note that your need `... \refline{} and ...` in the last line of the text, otherwise the following space will be gobbled.